# In this sentence, does "we had great fun" act as a relative clause to modify "the last time"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> "The last time we had great fun was when we were visiting the Water
>   Park."

In the sentence, does "*we had great fun*" act as a relative clause to modify "*the last time*"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It could be an ***integrated relative clause***, and it happens to also be part of the subject noun phrase.

Consider:

- 1) "[ The last time(i) *[ (that) we had great fun __(i) ] ]* **was** [ when we were visiting the Water Park ]."

The subject is:

- 2) The last time(i) *[ (that) we had great fun __(i) ]*

And the relative clause is:

- 3) *(that) we had great fun __(i)*

which could have as a possible non-relative version:

- 4) "We had great fun [last week]."

Relativize the noun phrase "last week", and we could then get back to your original:

- 2) The last time(i) *[ (that) we had great fun __(i) ]*

Notice that you could have also used the word "when" in your relative clause:

- The last time(i) *[ **when** we had great fun __(i) ]*

(Aside: Notice that the complement in your original example ("when we were visiting the Water Park") could be a ***fused relative***, where it can be glossed as meaning *"the time(i) [ when(i) we were visiting the Water Park __(i) ]"*.)

Comment: Thank you very much! In the construction "the last time we had great fun”, "last time" acts as the time adverbial. So do you mean that we could use "that" to replace "when" in this situation? In addition, both of them can be omitted?

Comment: It seems so, imo. :) Also, perhaps compare to: *"The last time when we had gotten together . . ."*

Comment: +1 :) Is this a cleft btw? If so, which way round is it so to speak? I mean, do you reckon it's more like *My two front teeth is what I want for Christmas* or *What I want for Christmas is my two front teeth*? Any thoughts?

Comment: @Araucaria At first blush (and almost 4 AM my time), I'm seeing this as two NPs: "NP1 was NP2". For the RHS seems to be a fused-relative (imo), not an embedded interrogative (which I had first wondered about). For if the RHS was treated as an embedded interrogative, it doesn't quite seem to work: *"The last time (that) we had great fun" was the answer to the question "When were we visiting the Water Park?"* (it seems to be off, imo). But as to being some kind of cleft, hmm, it seems, thinking roughly, that the uncleft version would then be: (cont.)

Comment: @Araucaria (cont.) *"We were visiting the Water Park [the last time (that/when) we had great fun]",* and so, perhaps a kind of cleft version, *"[The last time (that/when) we had great fun] was [when we were visiting the Water Park]"* (the OP's original). What do you think?

Comment: @Araucaria 2002 CGEL seems mostly discussing "What" pseudo-clefts. I might have to look at the 1985 Quirk et al. to find info.

Comment: @Araucaria There's a little bit in 1985 Quirk: page 1388, section 18.30. "Clauses with *who, where,* and *when* are sometimes acceptable, but mainly when the (wh-clause is subject complement: . . ."

Comment: @Araucaria You're probably fresher now than me, and so, I'll let you dive into this. :)

Comment: I think *[When we had great fun] was [when we were visiting the Water Park]* is almost definitely some kind of cleft. I'm not really sure about *[The last time (when) we had fun] was ...

Comment: @Araucaria Compare: "***The time*** [when we had great fun] was ***the time*** [when we were visiting the Water Park]", which appears to be "NP1 was NP2"; and it might correspond to your original if your original was parsed as two fused relatives?

Comment: Yes,probably so. The reason I'm not sure is that pseudo clefts look a bit like that to me anyhow: *What I enjoy is ice-cream*, *What I enjoy is Sachmo playing the trumpet* *What I enjoy is when Sachmo plays the trumpet.* *What I enjoy is exactly what she enjoys.* *What she enjoys is what **I** enjoy*. I can't quite tell if there is some kind of clefting/inversion going on when both NPs are fused relatives ... or even if the first NP has an RC. *The time we had most fun was Christmas*. It seems like a non-canonical version of *Christmas was the time we had most fun*

Comment: @Araucaria There's also the related info in 2002 *CGEL*, pages 268-9, [52], such as *"What he wanted to know was what I told her",* which can involve a fused relative and a subordinate interrogative. (In a margin is my comment which asks why it couldn't be seen as two fused relatives.)